# PyQt5 using custom QDockWidget from Designer ui file

Tags: pyqt5, qdockwidget

I'm trying to build an app with extensive use of QDockwidgets. However, I've found that I cannot use QDockwidgets made in Qt Designer.

Here's my customized dockwidget.ui as displayed in Designer:

[image]

Here's the QMainWindow form main2.ui with promoted widget (called DockWidget with instance name dw)

[image]

Here's what the finished app looks like. The dockwidget is completely empty. Are there any tricks to getting a QDockWidget form (ui file) from Designer to display properly in PyQt5?

[image]

main2.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, uic.loadUiType('main2.ui')[0]):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main(None)

main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

dockwidget.py

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDockWidget

# ~ form_class = uic.loadUiType('dockwidget.ui')[0]

class DockWidget(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('dockwidget.ui', self)
```

main2.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>390</width>
    <height>233</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>0</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>390</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <widget class="DockWidget" name="dw">
   <attribute name="dockWidgetArea">
    <number>4</number>
   </attribute>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents"/>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>DockWidget</class>
   <extends>QDockWidget</extends>
   <header>dockwidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

dockwidget.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>DockWidget</class>
 <widget class="QDockWidget" name="DockWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>328</width>
    <height>303</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="features">
   <set>QDockWidget::DockWidgetClosable|QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable</set>
  </property>
  <property name="allowedAreas">
   <set>Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea|Qt::TopDockWidgetArea</set>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>My Custom Dock Widget</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_5">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>RadioButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>RadioButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0">
     <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>RadioButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: The "problem" is that you're using a promoted QDockWidget class that already has a widget set for it, but Designer automatically sets *its own* widget on all dock widgets (similarly to what it does to scroll areas). Do you *actually* need the dock widget in the UI created in Designer?

Comment: The dock widget is actually much more complicated than I've shown, so there are many benefits to making a ui file in Designer. Even if Designer sets it's own widget (they call it dockWidgetContents), it would be desirable to be able to pull in the dock widget _and_ the widget. As a backup plan, I'm investigating making a widget as a Designer ui file that I can assign to the dock widget.

Comment: No, I meant: do you really need to add that dock widget to the main window UI in Designer? Because the problem is essentially there: if you can add it by code, then you don't need the promotion.

Comment: @musicamente. Hey, adding dock widget in code seems to work! If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept. Required changes only to main2.py. Add imports `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt` and `from dockwidget import DockWidget`. At end of __init__ add `dw1 = DockWidget()` and `self.addDockWidget(Qt.TopDockWidgetArea , dw1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to scroll areas, Designer creates a "contents" widget for new QDockWidgets. That widget is actually set using `setWidget()` when the main window UI is loaded, and it cannot be removed from Designer.

You already have a contents widget in your custom QDockWidget, but when it's added by the main ui, it's "overwritten" by it.

Consider that promoted classes that act as containers should only have their contents set *in the class* as long as the promoted widget does *not* change/override them, otherwise the previously set contents will be removed. For instance, if you create a custom widget with its layout and buttons, and use it as a promoted class in Designer, you cannot set another layout and add other children to that widget from there.

The only way to avoid the issue and actually create a customizable QDockWidget that already has basic contents set and can be added to a QMainWindow in Designer would be to create a Designer plugin. That's not easy, the documentation is complex and, especially for python, extremely poor (with support even missing for some classes).

There are various possibilities here, though:

1. the simplest: do *not* add the dock widget to the main window in Designer, but only by explicitly calling `addDockWidget()` in your code;
2. create a promoted class for the dock widget *contents* (a basic QWidget/form), and promote the `dockWidgetContents` of the dock widget that is added to the main window ui;
3. as long as you are *completely* sure that you will *never* call again `setWidget()` on the dock widget, and you *really* need the dock widget in the main window of Designer, override `setWidget()` in a similar way:

```py
class DockWidget(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('dockwidget.ui', self)

    def setWidget(self, widget):
        if self.widget() is None:
            super().setWidget(widget)
```

with the above code, the `setWidget()` call made by uic/setupUi of the main window  will be ignored, as at that point the dock widget already has a widget set by its own `loadUi`.

Comment: Nice answer. In my case, option 3 is the most attractive. It also seems to be compatible with option 1.

Comment: @bfris option 1 and 3 are compatible, but conceptually mutually exclusive: if you add the dock widget by code, `setWidget()` would be only called by the DockWidget's `loadUi()` call, but if you kept the promoted dock widget in the main window of Designer, you shall not call `addDockWidget()` anymore.